# Cast Map column to Struct column

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, dictionary, struct

I have a dataframe, and one of the columns is of map type. The map comes from a UDF and the existing columns of the dataframe.

How to transform the map column to a **struct type**?
I'm using Scala 2.10, and the column of map has more than 50 fields. So I don't want to use the **case class**.

Comment: Please read [ask] and produce a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is not enough information about how your data looks like and what is the kind of output you want, I'm writing this answer based on my understanding of your question.

```
val df = sqlContext.sql("""
select map(1,"a" ,2,"b" ,3,"c" ,4,"d" ,5,"e" ,6,"f" ,
7,"g" ,8,"h" ,9,"i" ,10,"j" ,11,"k" ,12,"l" ,13,"m" ,
14,"n" ,15,"o" ,16,"p" ,17,"q" ,18,"r" ,19,"s" ,20,"t" ,
21,"u" ,22,"v" ,23,"w" ,24,"x" ,25,"y" ,26,"z" )as mapcol 
""")
```

You can write a UDF to convert your map to any `Seq` type which would read as a `struct` in your dataframe. Each element of the struct will be a key-value pair separated with a comma (or whatever you want).

```
val toStruct = udf( (c1: Map[Int, String]) => c1.map {
    case (k,v) => k+","+v
}.toSeq)
```

Now, calling this UDF on your dataframe.

```
val structDF = df.withColumn("structcol", toStruct('mapcol) )
structDF.show
+--------------------+--------------------+
|              mapcol|           structcol|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|Map(5 -> e, 10 ->...|[5,e, 10,j, 24,x,...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

To fetch a single element:

```
structDF.selectExpr("structcol[0]").show

+------------+
|structcol[0]|
+------------+
|         5,e|
+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Struct from Map can be created without `udf`. But you will need to parse a new schema, because:

- Map only "knows" there's `key` and `value`, it doesn't specify individual types for keys
- there might be different keys in every record.

Input:

```scala
val df = Seq((Map(1->"a", 2->"b", 3->"c"))).toDF("mapcol")

df.show(truncate=false)
// +------------------------+
// |mapcol                  |
// +------------------------+
// |{1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c}|
// +------------------------+
```

Script:

```scala
val json_col = to_json($"mapcol")
val json_schema = spark.read.json(df.select(json_col).as[String]).schema
val df2 = df.withColumn("structcol", from_json(json_col, json_schema))

df2.show(truncate=false)
// +------------------------+---------+
// |mapcol                  |structcol|
// +------------------------+---------+
// |{1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c}|{a, b, c}|
// +------------------------+---------+

df2.printSchema()
// root
//  |-- mapcol: map (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- key: integer
//  |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
//  |-- structcol: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- 1: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- 2: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- 3: string (nullable = true)
```